# Jenkins builds with different slaves at a time

Tags: hudson, jenkins, master-slave

Whats is the best way to distribute different builds to different slave?

Can you give some examples how to restrict to particular node or all nodes or labeling is better?

I need to configuration examples.

I have 4 slaves

prod1-build
prod2-build
prod3-build and prod4-build

is it better to give a label as prodbuild adn restrict to prodbuild or

can I give prod1-build || prod2-buil || prod3-build || prod4-build

So when ever the build triggers it should pick any one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Labelling is best if you have a large number of jobs, as it's easier to manage; you just label your slaves and then add the appropriate label to each build job.

If you have a smaller number of jobs, you can also tie each individual job definition to a particular slave - in that case, just put the slave name in the "Restrict where this job can be run" field.

Comment: Okay thanks, but is there any way I can kick of same jobs in different nodes using labels, for example if I start a job it executes in one slave and after 15 mins if I execute it is not executing in different slave with same label name. Any thing can be done here?

Comment: By default, Jenkins will use the same slave for each successive execution of the same job. What's the reason you need to run the same job on multiple slaves ?

Comment: Say developer has check in something in one of the branches during first build is going on, so he can get the next build soon once he triggers the build after his next check ins.

Comment: Got it need to use Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin. Kwel